# How to resize a small image to large image without blur in php

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to resize a small image to large image in php , image resized but image gets blurred , Can anyone let me know how to avoid blurry .
   I tried with GD library and Imagick

Comment: Its not possible, it will be blurry

Comment: This isn't a PHP issue. The same thing would happen if you were to increase the size of an image in Photoshop.

Comment: @Saqueib Perhaps he is talking about enabling Nearest-neighbor interpolation to keep the pixel-y effect when it is enlarged.

Comment: @Brad ya maybe, but it will be blurry. its nature of Bitmap graphics, you can scale vector graphics `svg` but not with bitmap. there will be always quality lose